# Super Search, query strings and pagination after EE1.x->2.5.3 upgrade

Tags: supersearch, get, querystring

I'm currently in the process of upgrading a pretty complex EE1 site to 2.5.3. One of the thornier issues I've hit concerns EE2's handling of query strings and the interaction of this with native pagination.

The site uses Solspace's [Super Search module](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/super_search/) and I'm removing index.php via the standard exclude method, on EE1 I therefore had URLs of the format:

http://example.com/path/to/search&key=value&key2=value2.

On EE2.5.3, though super search works fine with URLs of this format, EE shows the $_GET array as empty (as shown in the template debugger output). I need to be able to access values in GET in my templates (I'm using [Mo'Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) for this), so have reformatted my search URLs to use a "?" instead like so:

http://example.com/path/to/search?key=value.

This works great for both super search and mo variables, but breaks on paginated output, as the pagination segment is appended to the end of the query string, like so:

http://example.com/path/to/search?key=value/P15

Which breaks Super Search, whereas what I need is to prepend the pagination segment to the query string:

http://example.com/path/to/search/P15?key=value

<strike>I'm reasonably sure there must be a way around this, even if it involves an addon instead of native pagination: devot-EE also uses Super Search and has a URL structure/pagination [just like what I'm looking to achieve](http://devot-ee.com/search/results/P10?keywords=pagination&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2),</strike> but I'm running up against a brick wall at the moment. Any and all bright ideas gratefully received.

*Edit: as noted in the comments to below Devot-ee now uses [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) instead of Super Search*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I was unable to resolve this with SuperSearch, so ultimately I decided to migrate to [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) instead, which was a reasonably painless process and seems to be working well.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with the 'paginate_base' parameter in the [exp:super_search:results tag](http://www.solspace.com/docs/detail/super_search_results/)? Weirdly, I don't find any reference to this parameter in the documentation, but I'm using it in all my sites.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but unfortunately `paginate_base` doesn't do the trick - the pagination segment is still appended to the end of the URL (inc query string) rather than between the template path and query string

Comment: In fact I'm not sure that SuperSearch like the ? so much. Here I have /search/search&keywords=test&start=0/, then /search/search&keywords=test&start=0/P10/ for the next page, which works fine. But not sure that Mo Vars will work without the ?... Maybe you could use POST instead of GET?

Comment: I need to use GET so that search results are bookmarkable. I'm pretty sure this can be made to work - see the devotee page I linked to above...

Comment: In case it helps with the troubleshooting to know this, Devot:ee used to use Super Search but [switched to using Low Search](http://devot-ee.com/news/item/this-week-in-devotee-august-23-2012) a little while back.

Comment: Thanks for that - now feel bad for sending them an email asking the same qn.

Comment: What about a rewrite rule in htaccess? I'm not an expert but something like rewriteRule ^search&[.*]/P[\d]/$ search/$2?$1 should do the trick.

Comment: hmm hadn't thought of that approach. will give it a shot, thanks